# Does Analysis Courses count as calculus?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am planning to apply for a Grad program in “transportation engineering” which requires the following:

- 1 year of college-level calculus
- 1 semester of elementary linear algebra

Now, I have taken the following courses in my undergraduate:

- Analysis & Linear Algebra - 1
- Analysis & Linear Algebra - 2
- Real Analysis
- Linear Algebra

The first two are introductory courses whereas the next two are advanced courses. Does these count as “1 year of calculus”?

Comment: What did you study in “real analysis”?

Comment: One would imagine so.   Did you cover limits, continuity, differentiation, integration,  integration by parts,  trig subsititutions,  etc.?

Comment: @Alan yes.All of that (but in single variable)

Comment: This seems like calculus then.

Comment: @user925032: Analysis, especially at an introductory level, might be described as a proof-based version of calculus. In caclulus, you might have to apply the chain rule in 20 different practice problems, whereas in analysis, you would be more interested in the proof of the chain rule than applying it.

Comment: @TymaGaidash compact sets, metric spaces, mean value thms, Riemann stieltjes integral, convergence (apart from @Alan’s comment)

Comment: My query is: Do grad schools count analysis as calculus courses in application?

Comment: 100% yes. Analysis is better than calculus, even. Except that it involves slightly less application, which might be a sticking point for some.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps oddly, the apparently high-quality mathematics you studied (which surely helps serious understanding...) is not quite the same thing as facility with operational manipulation of those ideas, in computational and heuristic settings. A "calculus course" would entail lots of computational examples, which you might not see in a more serious course.

One analogue would be that a person studying "number theory" could conceivably fail to be acquainted with the multiplication table up to 15-times-15, etc.

So, bottom line, facility with basic-and-computational things is what you'll need. Nevertheless, the people looking at your application will almost surely imagine that a fancier version of calculus completely subsumes a more basic version. That's not at all necessarily true... but... :)